# Can an Animagus retain their wand in animal form?

Tags: harry-potter, animagi

If an Animagus transforms to their animal form, can they pack their wand such that they get it back when they transform back to human form even if they travel far from where they have transformed?

I don't recall any example in canon that would decide this.  We see McGonagall untransform in Stone chapter 1, but we don't learn whether she has a wand with her.  Neither Sirius nor Wormtail have had a wand of their own during the events of Prisoner, and we rarely see them transform in the later books.  Sirius transforms during Goblet when he goes to the railway station, but does not untrasform until he returns to the Headquarters.  Rita Skeeter presumably never untransforms in Hogwarts, because of the risk of getting caught.

One relevant event is when Lupin transforms to a werewolf in Prisoner chapter 20: he drops his wand.  However, Lupin was unprepared for the transformation at that time, and maybe he could have “packed” the wand if he prepares to transform.  Besides, the rules could differ for a werewolf and an Animagus.

See the related question [What determines whether or not an animagus can retain their clothes?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11372/what-determines-whether-or-not-an-animagus-can-retain-their-clothes) which explains that we believe an Animagus can keep their clothes at least, and [In HP Goblet of Fire.. How does the Body of Cedric Come out of Voldemort's wand when he was killed by Wormtail?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8817/in-hp-goblet-of-fire-how-does-the-body-of-cedric-come-out-of-voldemorts-wand) where this question has come up.

Comment: A co-ed boarding school for teenagers? There must have been all sorts of wand-packing going on.

Comment: @JohnO - thanks for stabbing me in the childhood... with your wand

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/97010/4918 on whether you need a wand to transform.

Comment: @b_jonas Have you read the new content yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No

> When your transformation is complete you should find yourself physically comfortable. You are strongly advised to pick up your wand at once, and hide it in a place of safekeeping, where you will be able to find it when you regain a human form.
>   <sub>[Pottermore - Animagi](https://usd.shop.pottermore.com/products/short_stories_from_hogwarts_of_heroism_hardship_and_dangerous_hobbies_ebook_english) (behind paywall)</sub>

This would show that Animagi do not retain their wands.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, of course. We have proved that they can pack their clothing ([What determines whether or not an animagus can retain their clothes?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11372/1660)), and, essentially, **a wand is no different**.

I'll quote a quote you did in your answer there:

> ‘[...] Look very closely, and you'll notice the markings around her
>   antennae are exactly like those foul glasses she wears.’

Okay, so glasses can be taken at will. Glasses, wands, what's the difference? My point is: there is nothing that makes a wand particularly hard to retain.

Or well, let us take a different approach: Wands - wooden sticks with a core (phoenix feather, for instance). No matter how uncomfortable it would be, clothing can still be made with wood-based material (as decoration on a shirt, perhaps), and feathers can undoubtedly be used for all kinds of clothing. So a wand, essentially, could be categorized as clothing due to the simple materials. Thus, as clothing, wands can be packed by the animagus.

Or heartstring. No idea what the hell it is, but if it is a string of some sort, I'd expect to be able to make some kind of clothing with it :).

The fact that wands are magical (unlike glasses) shouldn't present an obstacle either - there doesn't seem to be any proof that magical items are "harder to work with".

Comment: What a heartstring is was answered on this site before :)

Comment: @DVK: Lol! Totally unexpected. Looks string-enough for some (very bizarre) clothing though :)

Answer (score 5):

From the Tales of Beedle the Bard:

> When the grounds were deserted once more, there wriggled from a hole between the roots of  the tree stump a stout and whiskery old rabbit with a wand clamped between her teeth...
>
> -*Babbity Rabbity and her Cackling Stump*

This was at the end of the story after Babbity Rabbity had transformed into a rabbit.

Note that she retained her wand by **clamping it between her teeth**.

There may be other ways of storing or retaining one's wand once transformed as an Animagus, but (entering into speculation territory now) if I were a wizard, there would be absolutely no circumstance in which I would leave my wand behind.

**Note:**
As Albus Dumbledore points out in the foot-notes to this story; it was likely that Beedle did not actually know the exact abilities / limitations of an Animagus:

> I think it more likely that Beedle had only heard about Animagi, and never met one...
>
> -*Albus Dumbledore, Foot-notes, Babbity Rabbity and her Cackling Stump, Tales of Beedle the Bard*

Therefore, the wand clamped between the rabbit's teeth might have been a logical construct of Beedle's.