# Can an Animagus transform into a magical beast?

Tags: harry-potter, animagi

Let's say I am a wizard, and I possess the ability to become an Animagus.  Could I choose a Phoenix to be the animal that I transform into?  And would I acquire the Phoenix's power of regeneration?

Comment: ['One thing we DO know is that JKR indicated that your Animagus form is NOT something you get to pick and choose and you wouldn't know it before transforming the first time... so you can't simply just pick something "cool".'](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/53743/46611)

Comment: That is very interesting.  With that in mind, Krum was super lucky during the Tri-Wizard tournament.  Imagine he's preparing for the underwater event by practicing his self-transfiguration and he discovers that his animal was something like a camel or a hummingbird.

Comment: I think what Krum did was general transfiguration, not an animagus transformation. It seems the difference is that one requires a wand, the other you can do whenever you want.

Comment: Ah okay.  That makes sense.